# Is it possible to mock out a .NET HttpWebResponse?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

i've got an integration test that grabs some json result from a 3rd party server. It's really simple and works great.

I was hoping to stop actually hitting this server and using `Moq` (or any Mocking library, like ninject, etc) to hijack and force the return result.

is this possible?

Here is some sample code :-

```
public Foo GoGetSomeJsonForMePleaseKThxBai()
{
    // prep stuff ...

    // Now get json please.
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("Http://some.fancypants.site/api/hiThere");
    httpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
    
    string responseText;
    
    using (var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            json = streamReader.ReadToEnd().ToLowerInvariant();
        }
    }
    
    // Check the value of the json... etc..
}
```

and of course, this method is called from my test.

I was thinking that maybe I need to pass into this method (or a property of the class?) a mocked `httpWebResponse` or something but wasn't too sure if this was the way. Also, the response is a output from an `httpWebRequest.GetResponse()` method .. so maybe I just need to pass in a mocked `HttpWebRequest` ?.

any suggestions with some sample code would be most aprreciated!

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You may wish to change your consuming code to take in an interface for a factory that creates requests and responses that can be mocked which wrap the actual implementation.

### Update: Revisiting

I've been getting downvotes long after my answer was accepted, and I admit my original answer was poor quality and made a big assumption.

#### Mocking HttpWebRequest in 4.5+

The confusion from my original answer lies in the fact that you can mock `HttpWebResponse` in 4.5, but not earlier versions. Mocking it in 4.5 also utilizes obsolete constructors. So, the recommended course of action is to abstract the request and response. Anyways, below is a complete working test using .NET 4.5 with Moq 4.2.

```
[Test]
public void Create_should_create_request_and_respond_with_stream()
{
    // arrange
    var expected = "response content";
    var expectedBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(expected);
    var responseStream = new MemoryStream();
    responseStream.Write(expectedBytes, 0, expectedBytes.Length);
    responseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    var response = new Mock<HttpWebResponse>();
    response.Setup(c => c.GetResponseStream()).Returns(responseStream);

    var request = new Mock<HttpWebRequest>();
    request.Setup(c => c.GetResponse()).Returns(response.Object);

    var factory = new Mock<IHttpWebRequestFactory>();
    factory.Setup(c => c.Create(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns(request.Object);

    // act
    var actualRequest = factory.Object.Create("http://www.google.com");
    actualRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;

    string actual;

    using (var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)actualRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            actual = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }


    // assert
    actual.Should().Be(expected);
}

public interface IHttpWebRequestFactory
{
    HttpWebRequest Create(string uri);
}
```

#### Better answer: Abstract the Response and Request

Here's a safer bare-bones implementation of an abstraction that will work for prior versions (well, down to 3.5 at least):

```
[Test]
public void Create_should_create_request_and_respond_with_stream()
{
    // arrange
    var expected = "response content";
    var expectedBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(expected);
    var responseStream = new MemoryStream();
    responseStream.Write(expectedBytes, 0, expectedBytes.Length);
    responseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    var response = new Mock<IHttpWebResponse>();
    response.Setup(c => c.GetResponseStream()).Returns(responseStream);

    var request = new Mock<IHttpWebRequest>();
    request.Setup(c => c.GetResponse()).Returns(response.Object);

    var factory = new Mock<IHttpWebRequestFactory>();
    factory.Setup(c => c.Create(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns(request.Object);

    // act
    var actualRequest = factory.Object.Create("http://www.google.com");
    actualRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;

    string actual;

    using (var httpWebResponse = actualRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            actual = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }


    // assert
    actual.Should().Be(expected);
}

public interface IHttpWebRequest
{
    // expose the members you need
    string Method { get; set; }

    IHttpWebResponse GetResponse();
}

public interface IHttpWebResponse : IDisposable
{
    // expose the members you need
    Stream GetResponseStream();
}

public interface IHttpWebRequestFactory
{
    IHttpWebRequest Create(string uri);
}

// barebones implementation

private class HttpWebRequestFactory : IHttpWebRequestFactory
{
    public IHttpWebRequest Create(string uri)
    {
        return new WrapHttpWebRequest((HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri));
    }
}

public class WrapHttpWebRequest : IHttpWebRequest
{
    private readonly HttpWebRequest _request;

    public WrapHttpWebRequest(HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        _request = request;
    }

    public string Method
    {
        get { return _request.Method; }
        set { _request.Method = value; }
    }

    public IHttpWebResponse GetResponse()
    {
        return new WrapHttpWebResponse((HttpWebResponse)_request.GetResponse());
    }
}

public class WrapHttpWebResponse : IHttpWebResponse
{
    private WebResponse _response;

    public WrapHttpWebResponse(HttpWebResponse response)
    {
        _response = response;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_response != null)
            {
                ((IDisposable)_response).Dispose();
                _response = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public Stream GetResponseStream()
    {
        return _response.GetResponseStream();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't create mock for HttpWebResponse. You wil get an error like this:"System.ArgumentException: Can not instantiate proxy of class: System.Net.HttpWebResponse. Could not find a parameterless constructor. Parameter name: constructorArguments"

Comment: I am unable to find the .Net framework which supports Is IHttpWebRequest, IHttpWebRequestFactory, IHttpWebResponse. Any ideas?

Comment: @AjitGoel They are interfaces you would have to create, which I supplied in my example. Scroll down on the second code sample, it's there.

Comment: @HackedByChinese: Dont know how I missed it. Need coffee to wake me up.

Comment: Is there a good reason for using IHttpWebRequestFactory? Can't we just keep the Create method inside the IHttpWebRequest interface?

Comment: @IvanStudenikin Whether it were included in the interface or not, some Create method would have to be implemented.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than mocking out the HttpWebResponse is I would wrap the call behind an interface, and mock that interface.

If you are testing does the web response hit the site I want it too, that is a different test than if does class A call the WebResponse interface to get the needed data.

For mocking an interface I prefer [Rhino mocks](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/open-source/rhino-mocks).   See [here](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/open-source/rhino-mocks) on how to use it.

Comment: The method (above) is actually an implimented interface. So the class is `public class AwesomeClass : IThinkICan`. So you're suggestion i just mock that class instead, so i mock the return object? Right now, my test does hit the 3rd party, but i do not want it to do that. (ie. go from integration test to a unit test).

Answer (score 5):

None of the Microsoft's HTTP stack was developed with unit testing and separation in mind.

You have three options:

- Make the call to web as small as possible (i.e. send and get back data and pass to other methods) and test the rest. As far as the web call is concerned, there should be much magic happening there and very straightforward.
- Wrap the HTTP call in another class and pass your mock object while testing.
- Wrap `HttpWebResponse` and `HttpWebRequest` by two other classes. This is what the MVC team did with `HttpContext`.

Second option:

```
interface IWebCaller
{
    string CallWeb(string address);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If it helps please find below the code illustrated in the accepted answer using NSubstitute in place of Moq

```
using NSubstitute; /*+ other assemblies*/

[TestMethod]
public void Create_should_create_request_and_respond_with_stream()
{
   //Arrange
   var expected = "response content";
   var expectedBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(expected);
   var responseStream = new MemoryStream();
   responseStream.Write(expectedBytes, 0, expectedBytes.Length);
   responseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

   var response = Substitute.For<HttpWebResponse>();
   response.GetResponseStream().Returns(responseStream);

   var request = Substitute.For<HttpWebRequest>();
   request.GetResponse().Returns(response);

   var factory = Substitute.For<IHttpWebRequestFactory>();
   factory.Create(Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(request);

   //Act
   var actualRequest = factory.Create("http://www.google.com");
   actualRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;

   string actual;

   using (var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)actualRequest.GetResponse())
   {
       using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
       {
           actual = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
       }
   }

   //Assert
   Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}

public interface IHttpWebRequestFactory
{
    HttpWebRequest Create(string uri);
}
```

Unit Test run and passes successfully.

Up vote given on the answer I've been looking for some time how to do this effectively.

Comment: giving downvote because this is not working at all:

```var r = Substitute.For<HttpWebResponse>();

Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException: Can not instantiate proxy of class: System.Net.HttpWebResponse.```

Comment: damn, cant edit my comment, so will add another: you cannot use substitute for .Net 3.5 variant of this class. higher versions got default constructor. but also in higher versions the default constructor is public so you may simple instantiate this class instead of mocking

Answer (score 1):

You can actually return `HttpWebResponse` without mocking, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87200/mocking-webresponses-from-a-webrequest/10882731#10882731).  It does not require any "external" proxying interfaces, only the "standard" `WebRequest` `WebResponse` and `ICreateWebRequest`.

If you don't need access to `HttpWebResponse` and can deal with just `WebResponse` it is even easier; we do that in our unit tests to return "prefabricated" content responses for consumption.  I had to "go the extra mile" in order to return actual HTTP status codes, to simulate e.g. 404 responses which requires you use `HttpWebResponse` so you can access the `StatusCode` property et al.

The other solutions assuming everything is `HttpWebXXX` **ignores everything supported by `WebRequest.Create()` except HTTP**, which can be a handler for any registered prefix you care to use (via `WebRequest.RegisterPrefix()` and if you are ignoring that, you are missing out, because it is a great way to expose other content streams you otherwise have no way to access, e.g. Embeeded Resource Streams, File streams, etc.

Also, explicitly casting the return of `WebRequest.Create()` to `HttpWebRequest` is **a path to breakage**, since the method return type is `WebRequest` and again, shows some ignorance of how that API actually works.

Answer (score 1):

Although there is an accepted answer, I would like to share my view. There are many times that modifying the source code is not an option as suggested. Furthermore the answer introduces to say the least a lot of production code.

So I prefer to use the free [harmonyLib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/lib.harmony) and patch the CLR without any change in the production code, by intercepting the `WebRequest.Create` static method.

My modified version looks like:

```
        public static bool CreateWithSomeContent(ref WebRequest __result){
            var expected = "response content";
            var expectedBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(expected);
            var responseStream = new MemoryStream();
            responseStream.Write(expectedBytes, 0, expectedBytes.Length);
            responseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            var response = new Mock<HttpWebResponse>();
            response.Setup(c => c.GetResponseStream()).Returns(responseStream);

            var requestMock = new Mock<HttpWebRequest>();
            requestMock.Setup(c => c.GetResponse()).Returns(response.Object);
            __result = requestMock.Object;
            return false;
        }

        [Test]
        public void Create_should_create_request_and_respond_with_stream(){
            //arrange
            var harmony = new Harmony(nameof(Create_should_create_request_and_respond_with_stream));
            var methodInfo = typeof(WebRequest).GetMethod("Create",new Type[]{typeof(string)});
            harmony.Patch(methodInfo, new HarmonyMethod(GetType(), nameof(CreateWithSomeContent)){});

            //act
            var actualRequest = WebRequest.Create("");
            string actual;
            using (var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)actualRequest.GetResponse()){
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())){
                    actual = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            
            // assert
            // actual.Should().Be("response content");
        }
```

Comment: Moq to the rescue! Following code helped me a lot:
var httpWebResponseMock = new Mock<HttpWebResponse>();

Answer (score -1):

I Found a great solution in this [blog post](http://blog.salamandersoft.co.uk/index.php/2009/10/how-to-mock-httpwebrequest-when-unit-testing/):

It´s very easy to use, you just need to do this:

```
string response = "my response string here";
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("test", new TestWebRequestCreate());
TestWebRequest request = TestWebRequestCreate.CreateTestRequest(response);
```

And copy those files to your project:

```
    class TestWebRequestCreate : IWebRequestCreate
{
    static WebRequest nextRequest;
    static object lockObject = new object();

    static public WebRequest NextRequest
    {
        get { return nextRequest ;}
        set
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                nextRequest = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>See <see cref="IWebRequestCreate.Create"/>.</summary>
    public WebRequest Create(Uri uri)
    {
        return nextRequest;
    }

    /// <summary>Utility method for creating a TestWebRequest and setting
    /// it to be the next WebRequest to use.</summary>
    /// <param name="response">The response the TestWebRequest will return.</param>
    public static TestWebRequest CreateTestRequest(string response)
    {
        TestWebRequest request = new TestWebRequest(response);
        NextRequest = request;
        return request;
    }
}

class TestWebRequest : WebRequest
{
    MemoryStream requestStream = new MemoryStream();
    MemoryStream responseStream;

    public override string Method { get; set; }
    public override string ContentType { get; set; }
    public override long ContentLength { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Initializes a new instance of <see cref="TestWebRequest"/>
    /// with the response to return.</summary>
    public TestWebRequest(string response)
    {
        responseStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response));
    }

    /// <summary>Returns the request contents as a string.</summary>
    public string ContentAsString()
    {
        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(requestStream.ToArray());
    }

    /// <summary>See <see cref="WebRequest.GetRequestStream"/>.</summary>
    public override Stream GetRequestStream()
    {
        return requestStream;
    }

    /// <summary>See <see cref="WebRequest.GetResponse"/>.</summary>
    public override WebResponse GetResponse()
    {
        return new TestWebReponse(responseStream);
    }
}

class TestWebReponse : WebResponse
{
    Stream responseStream;

    /// <summary>Initializes a new instance of <see cref="TestWebReponse"/>
    /// with the response stream to return.</summary>
    public TestWebReponse(Stream responseStream)
    {
        this.responseStream = responseStream;
    }

    /// <summary>See <see cref="WebResponse.GetResponseStream"/>.</summary>
    public override Stream GetResponseStream()
    {
        return responseStream;
    }
}
```

Comment: this makes no reference to HttpWebResponse. as soon as you cast TestWebResponse as HttpWebResponse it will be null.

Comment: @Christo when you call `WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("test", new TestWebRequestCreate());` you are registering a prefix for requests. So you have to mock the url too: using  **test**://example.com instead of **http**://example.com

Comment: the post you found is cool and useful for testing WebRequest/Response etc. but the original question was how can i test ```HttpWebRequest```. if you use this code to test the code in the question it would fail trying to explicitly convert ```TestWebReponse``` to ```HttpWebRequest```. line 4 of his method

Comment: @Christo I think you mean convert `TestWebReponse` to `HttpWebResponse` and `TestWebRequest` to `HttpWebRequest`.

In this case you just have to change the inheritance from `TestWebRequest` and `TestWebReponse` to inherit from `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` respectively

Comment: sorry for the typo. i did mean that. i suggest you test these suggestions as i dont think that would work.