# Unit test a class that uses HttpClient in System.Net.Http v4

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I wants unit test the Search class below that uses HttpClient,

```
public class Search:ISearch{
HttpClient httpClient;
  public Search(HttpClient httpClient){
   this.httpClient = httpClient;
}
   //use httClient to send request.
}
```

Is there a way to mock the HttpClient? I cannot find any information via Google.

**Update**

Is there an alternaitve to sending an Http web request that can be mocked. I have the code below:

```
 public class Search:ISearch{
private static readonly string url = "http://www.google.com/search";
public Result SendSearch(string query){
           string queryUrl = string.Format("{0}?q={1}", url, query);
           var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(queryUrl);
          ///...
}
```

Comment: Hmm, do you really want to mock a part of the framework?  I don't see how this would gain you anything, but perhaps I'm just missing your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mock it with a mocking framework like Rhino-Mocks, because in order to do that you need either an `interface` or `virtual methods` on the `HttpClient` class. A mocking framework will create a mock for you, that either implements the methods defined on the interface or overrides the methods of your virtual class.

So either you wrap the `HttpClient` class and let it implement an interface, or, don't mock it.

If you'd change your code to something like this:

```
public class Search:ISearch
{
    private static readonly string url = "http://www.google.com/search";
    private readonly IWebRequestCreator _generator;

    public Search(IWebRequestCreator generator)
    {
        _generator = generator;
    }

    public Result SendSearch(string query)
    {
        var queryUrl = string.Format("{0}?q={1}", url, query);
        var webRequest = _generator.Create(queryUrl);
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you create a class that implements the `IWebRequestCreator` then you'd be able to mock the functionality. The implementing class would just call `WebRequest.Create(queryUrl);`

Comment: Yeah, wrap it :). Not sure how your caller of `Search` is defined, but maybe you can steal some ideas from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823039/is-it-possible-to-mock-out-a-net-httpwebresponse

Comment: @Pingpong made an update according to your update in your question

Answer (score 3):

In .Net 4.5 framework you can do this.

```
public class FakeHttpMessageHandler : HttpMessageHandler
{
    private HttpResponseMessage response;

    public FakeHttpMessageHandler(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        this.response = response;
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var responseTask =  new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
        responseTask.SetResult(response);

        return responseTask.Task;
    }
}


[TestMethod]
public void TestGetContents()
{
    var responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
    var messageHandler = new FakeHttpMessageHandler(responseMessage);
    var client = new HttpClient(messageHandler);
    var sut = new Search(client);

    sut.SendSearch("urQuery");

    // Asserts
}
```