# Set ContentEncoding when mocking WebResponse

Tags: c#, moq

I'm stuck on how to set the contentencoding property as it is not overridable via moq.

I currently have the following:

```
var expected = "dfgdfgdfgdfg";
var expectedBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(expected);
var responseStream = new MemoryStream();
responseStream.Write(expectedBytes, 0, expectedBytes.Length);
responseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

var response = new Mock<HttpWebResponse>();
response.Setup(c => c.GetResponseStream()).Returns(responseStream);
response.Setup(c => c.ContentEncoding).Returns("UTF8");
```

But I get the following exception:

```
 Result Message:    Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: c => c.ContentEncoding
```

Any idea how I can mock this property?

Comment: Try looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823039/is-it-possible-to-mock-out-a-net-httpwebresponse

Comment: @IlyaKogan Thanks, I had a look at that before however even with that example code the ContentEncoding prperty throws `'response.ContentEncoding' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what i would do:

```
      var webHeaderCollectionFieldInfo = typeof (HttpWebResponse).GetField("m_HttpResponseHeaders",
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

      var webHeaderCollection = new WebHeaderCollection();
      webHeaderCollection.Set("Content-Encoding", "cheese");
      webHeaderCollectionFieldInfo.SetValue(response.Object, webHeaderCollection);
```

Add that instead of your last line.

Comment: Wow! I went to bed disheartened but woke up to find your answer works like a charm! One thing I don't get though is, how is the webresponse class picking the content-encoding, because your code doesn't appear to be passed anywhere, is it something to do with the Set and SetValue methods?

Comment: @ImranAzad This code uses reflection. if you use at `HttpWebResponse.ContentEncoding` property you will see that it just returns a header out of private field collection, so that is what we got to set to get the outcome that you want.