# ViewResult.StatusCode is null despite explicitly setting it

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, xunit

I have written this controller method and this test.

Controller method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Metric(string type, string source)
{
    // Check existence ...

    var model = await _context
        .Metrics
        .FirstAsync(mt => mt.Type == metricType.AsInt() && mt.Source == source);

    Response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK.AsInt();

    return View(model);
}
```

Test:

```
[Fact]
public async Task MetricExistsTest()
{
    // Arrange ...

    // Act
    var result = await _controller.Metric(Metrics.CpuLoad.ToString(), "source-1");

    // Assert
    var viewResult = Assert.IsType<ViewResult>(result);

    Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK.AsInt(), viewResult.StatusCode.Value);

    var model = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<Metric>(
        viewResult.ViewData.Model
    );
}
```

Now, the problem is here `Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK.AsInt(), viewResult.StatusCode.Value);`. The `viewResult.StatusCode` is indeed `null`. If I comment that line out, everything works.

What am I doing wrong? Why is it `null`? Do I properly set `Response.StatusCode`? How do I verify status code then?

Thank you!

Comment: remove `Response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK.AsInt();` from within the action. the default response (in this case the view) should have 200 OK

Comment: @Nkosi and what if I want to set a custom code, like 204 No Content?

Comment: There are action results for that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/actions

Comment: @Nkosi - finally figured it out! See my answer. And thank you for help!

Answer (score 3):

I finally did it!
All those who helped me with answers and comments - I very much appreciate it!

It turns out that I had two problems - `HttpContext` does not exist (unless set manually) in testing environment and `Response.StatusCode` does not set `StatusCode` on resulting `ViewResult` object. (These are my observations, correct me if I'm wrong).

**Problem 1 solution:**

As simple as setting default `HttpContext` solves the problem. At least, controller method does not crash because `Response` is not `null` anymore.

```
var controller = new HomeController();

controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext();
controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
```

**Problem 2 solution:**

It turns out that I need to set `StatusCode` explicitly on `ViewResult` object. For some reason, ASP.Core does not mirror `StatusCode` from `Response` object to resulting `IActionObject`. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

So here is the solution (it's another method on my controller, but it clearly demonstrates the idea):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var model = await _context
        .Metrics
        .Where(mt => mt.Type == Metrics.CpuLoad.AsInt())
        .ToListAsync();

    var result = View(model);
    result.StatusCode = (model.Any() ? HttpStatusCode.OK : HttpStatusCode.NoContent).AsInt();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Note that a `204` response should not have a body/view, though. https://httpstatuses.com/204: "A 204 response is terminated by the first empty line after the header fields because it cannot contain a message body."

Comment: @hangy Very true. Don't get surprised when your browser refuses to load the content of 204 page, or even does not add the URL to history.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be Asserting the `result`, not the `viewresult`

```
[Fact]
public async Task MetricExistsTest()
{
    // Arrange ...

    // Act
    var result = await _controller.Metric(Metrics.CpuLoad.ToString(), "source-1");

    // Assert
    var viewResult = Assert.IsType<ViewResult>(result);

    Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK.AsInt(), result.StatusCode.Value);

    var model = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<Metric>(
        viewResult.ViewData.Model
    );
}
```

Comment: It turns out that `Response` is `null` in my controller method. Do you have an idea why? And how to set it properly?

Comment: You should be able to mock the HTTPResonse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823039/is-it-possible-to-mock-out-a-net-httpwebresponse

Comment: I was able to set default response object. But still `IActionResult` does not have `.StatusCode`, so I cannot write `result.StatusCode.Value`.

Comment: Mocking did not work for me, unfortunately, but thank you for the answer!