# cHttpWebResponse from class inherits WebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebresponse

I am trying to cast a class that inherits WebRequest to HttWebRequest (since I cannot inherit HttpWebRequest directly) but I get that the cast is not valid. Any idea how I can get a HttpWebRequest from my instance?

This is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        WebRequest wr = new WR("bla");
        HttpWebResponse webres = (HttpWebResponse) wr; // this fails
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public class WR : WebRequest
    {
        private string bla;
        private Uri url;

        public WR(string x)
        {
            bla = x;
        }

        public override Uri RequestUri
        {
            get { return this.url; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's because WebRequest does not inherit HttpWebRequest, but HttpWebRequest inherits WebRequest. Change "WebRequest" to "HttpWebRequest". To give an example. Ex. you have a base class named "Human" which you inherit from a class named "Boy". However you can a class named "Girl" too which inherits "Human". Neither "Boy" or "Girl" can convert to each other. Since they're both "Human", but not the same.

Comment: Note that you'd normally get a `WebResponse` (or `HttpWebResponse`) by calling `.GetResponse()` on the original `WebRequest` object.  Certainly not by casting a request to a response.

Comment: What do you really want to achieve? Why do you need your own `WebRequest` derived class? Why not use standard facilities? Or encapsulate `WebRequest` - `WebResponse` stuff inside some custom class?

Comment: I'm trying to mock a WebRequest.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87200/mocking-webresponses-from-a-webrequest)?

Answer (score 0):

Heritage simply cannot work this way. HttpWebRequest is a *more specific* version of WebRequest. Since you only inherit from WebRequest, your object cannot satisfy HttpWebRequest.

If you do need some fields from HttpWebRequest try [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) instead of heritage. Depending on your needs, you could make some class that basically possesses a *HttpWebRequest* field along your *WR* fields and function.

Note: This answer takes in account you cannot inherit from HttpWebRequest as you stated. I dont know why. If for some reason you realise you CAN inherit from HttpWebRequest, you should.

Answer (score -1):

what you need to write is....

HttpWebResponse webres = new HttpWebResponse();